# Using cocos2d-x as a static library results in linker errors on mac os

Tags: cocos2d-x, libtool-xcode

I am trying to use cocos2d-x as a game engine, and I have already tried using RubyMotion and MonoTouch to check if it is possible to use cocos2d-x binaries. 
But both, RubyMotion and MonoTouch, are suffering from the same linker error:

```
  duplicate symbol _SHA1 in:
    libcocos2dx.a(sha-1.o)
    libcocos2dx.a(sha1_one.o)
```

I did a research and figured out following:
_SHA1 symbols are defined in libcurl.a which packed as precompiled static library inside of cocos2d-x externals. During building cocos2d-x XCode calls libtool to create a universal binary libcocos2dx.a And according to [this article](http://binaryfinery.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/universal-static-library-problem-in-iphone-sdk/) libtool itself creates duplicated symbols (in some cases related to category bug).
Though author states how he has solved similar problem in his case, I am not sure how to apply his solution to my case (if at all it can be applied).

I am not sure where to go from here, since I hoped to use either Ruby or C# to develop my game. Is it possible to solve this libtool/linker problem and get static library without duplicated symbols?

P.S. Please note that if I use same cocos2d-x binaries as a xcode project inside my XCode project, then everything is good. But I want to code in ruby/c#.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you could use project template for MacOS which comes with cocos2d-x samples. We've made several projects (two of them are already at the store) this way.

Comment: I can't find samples in the github repo. Could you please clarify where I can find them?

Comment: Now I understand what you advice is =). This is not an option in case if I want to develop a game project using Xamarin, or RubyMotion, because in this case libtool problem arises exactly as I described above.

Comment: In XCode there some linker flags. In our projects there are several of the, for example: -fobjc-arc -all_load -ObjC. Try to use them all (or not all, now I cannot say which ones are used for cocos2d-x lib) in your XCode project or find something similar in case of using another environment. Hope it will help you.